# My Laravel project don't conect to XAMPP DataBase

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5, homestead

I've followed good tutorials on the web and I do make, I've made step by step its advices and I don't achive to conect my laravel framework to XAMPP.. I don't have idea what's going on.. I've written down the .env and config/database.php with the same data configurations (DB_DATABASE= styde_curso, DB_USERNAME= root, and DB_PASSWORD= ).

.env

```
APP_NAME=Prueba
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:MWU6YadaT17Ga1m3hrtOQqYq6pIwOgrNWQe+mJazyw0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=homestead.test
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=styde_curso
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [

            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'styde_curso'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Although I'd applied "php artisan config:clear" I'm getting the same result "ERROR" I've copied the error that git hub notices me:

> vagrant@homestead:~/code/Prueba$ php artisan config:clear
>   Configuration cache cleared! vagrant@homestead:~/code/Prueba$ php
>   artisan migrate
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select *
>   from information_schema.tables where table_schema = styde_curso and
>   table_name = migrations)
>
> at
>
> /home/vagrant/code/Prueba/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:
>   664

```
660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.

663|         catch (Exception $e) {
664|             throw new QueryException(
665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
666|             );
667|         }
668|
```

Exception trace:

> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
>   /home/vagrant/code/Prueba/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php
>   : 68
>
> 2
>   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=styde_curso",
>   "root", "", [])
>         /home/vagrant/code/Prueba/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php
>   : 68

I'll wait your help or whomever can help me.. 
    Thanx.

Comment: your local db username is `root` and without password like you have in config?

Comment: Did you restart the server after set the ENV variables?

Comment: Yes, my configuration is as is written above.. most of the time the password is empty on user root on XAMPP. And I've restarted my server as well. Furthermore I've changed in "ini.php" the var mysqli.default_host= mysql.sock and nothing is worrking

Answer (score 0):

- Sometimes this problem comes when you make changes to your **.env file** and not restarting the server. I would suggest you change  **'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')**, to **localhost**
- Restart your server, since the **config/database** is also written localhost

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting your DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

I would also suggest setting a password for the database root user if you have not already, this is just good practice. Be sure to update the .env file with the new password if you choose to do so.

The error is telling you the login failed:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The error is most likely either as a result of incorrect credentials (missing or wrong username/password). Or incorrect access, in other words, your user (in this case root) may have privileges as root@127.0.0.1 but not as root@localhost.